# Python - How to access first type of data

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
NumberTextSet3 = {"ten": 10, 
                  "hundred": 100,
                  "thousand": 1000,
                  "million": 1000000,
                  "billion": 1000000000,
                  "trillion": 1000000000000}
```

In this dictionary, I can access the number `1000000000000` by using `NumberTextSet3["trillion"]` .
But how would I access the the last word in the dictionary, maybe like: `NumberTextSet3[-1]` and have it return `"trillion"`?

Comment: You can see my updated answer. Hope, this is what you want.

Comment: So this question is about: **Get the last value in a dictionary**. What does **How to access first type of data** mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no last word in a dictionary.

To check it, try,

```
print NumberTextSet3
```

You will get different ordered result in different time.

You can slightly modify your data structure to `[("ten",10),("hundred",100),...]`

Now, you can use it with index.

For example,

```
a=[("ten",10),("hundred",100)]

print a[0][0]
print a[1][1]
```

Output:

```
ten
100
```

You can use an `OrderedDict` too

Answer (score 1):

I would use a OrderedDict like this:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

NumberTextSet3 = OrderedDict([("ten", 10),
                              ("hundred", 100),
                              ("thousand", 1000),
                              ("million", 1000000),
                              ("billion", 1000000000),
                              ("trillion", 1000000000000)])
# On Python2 this will work:
print NumberTextSet3.keys()[-1]
# This is a little bit longer but will work in Python2 and Python3:
print list(NumberTextSet3.keys())[-1]
```

Comment: `TypeError: 'KeysView' object does not support indexing`

Comment: Ok doesn't happen for me on Python 2.7.10

Comment: if you construct list before indexing, it should work always: `print list(NumberTextSet3.keys())[-1]` - is this working for you @KevinGuan ?

Comment: Well, I forgot you're on Python 2, I'm sorry for that. And `list(NumberTextSet3.keys())[-1]` will work on Python 3 :P

Comment: @KevinGuan Thanks for trying :)  I updated the answer.

Answer (score 0):

A dictionary is not ordered so it has no such thing as "first" or "last" entry. You *can* access a specific key as follows:

```
NumberTextSet3["trillion"]
```

or:

```
NumberTextSet3.get("trillion")
```

If you want to access the list of keys you can do:

```
NumberTextSet3.keys()
```

which return on my computer: `['billion', 'trillion', 'ten', 'thousand', 'million', 'hundred']`

and as you can see - there is no "order" here.

Comment: So would I need 2 lists? One for "trillion" and one for "1000000000000"?

Answer (score 0):

This can work although it's not guaranteed since dictionaries are not ordered.

```
NumberTextSet3.items()[-1][0]
```

Edit: You may want to use a list of tuples (below) instead; in which case the same technique would work since `items()` gives the dict in key/value pairs [tuple].

```
NumberTextSet3 = (("ten", 10), 
                  ("hundred", 100),
                  ("thousand", 1000),
                  ("million", 1000000),
                  ("billion", 1000000000),
                  ("trillion", 1000000000000))
```

Answer (score 0):

You would need to extract all of the entries and then sort them:

```
import operator

NumberTextSet3 = {"ten": 10, 
                  "hundred": 100,
                  "thousand": 1000,
                  "million": 1000000,
                  "billion": 1000000000,
                  "trillion": 1000000000000}

values = sorted(NumberTextSet3.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1))

print values[-1][0]
```

Giving:

```
trillion
```

If you wanted to do the reverse lookup, then you could create the inverse mapping as follows, and use that:

```
InverseNumberTextSet3 = {v: k for k, v in NumberTextSet3.items()}
print InverseNumberTextSet3[1000000000000]
```

Giving:

```
trillion
```

Answer (score 0):

Python dictionaries have no ordering guarantee.

Implementation-wise this stems from the fact that the dictionary is a hash map and the hashmap has its key ordering determined by the hash function (which is supposed to be pseudo-random).

So, while you can access the *first* and *last* items in your dictionary (`NumberTextSet3.items()[0]` and `NumberTextSet3.items()[-1]`, respectively) these probably do not correspond the order in which you created the dictionary.

However, the standard library provides [`collections.OrderedDict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict), which *preserves insertion order*, hence

```
from collections import OrderedDict

NumberTextSet3 = OrderedDict((
    ("ten", 10),
    ("hundred", 100),
    ("thousand", 1000),
    ("million", 1000000),
    ("billion", 1000000000),
    ("trillion", 1000000000000)
))

print(list(NumberTextSet3.keys())) 
=> ['ten', 'hundred', 'thousand', 'million', 'billion', 'trillion']
print(list(dict(NumberTextSet3).keys()))
=> ['million', 'hundred', 'ten', 'billion', 'thousand', 'trillion']
```

Be aware of the fact that I change the dictionary literal to a tuple list. Using a dictionary literal would not work, since this would create a temporary, unordered dictionary and than pass that to `OrderedDict`, which would freeze the (quasi-random) order.